# Assets/Scripts/Quıt.cs(10,21): error CS0117: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Quıt'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started playing games for the first time in Unity. I get the error in the title. Why could it be? Thanks.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

    public class Quıt : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        {
            Application.Quıt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a typo? A the number „1“ instead of the letter „i“ in the method Quit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to put it in a method. Also Application.Quit() does not work in the editor.

```
public class Quit : MonoBehaviour {

public void QuitApplication() {
Application.Quit();
}

}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationScriptingMethods.html